# Java Spring project : impact of delaying authentication implementation

Tags: java, spring, jwt

Is it possible to forget the authentication, jwt login stuff and security for now and implement it later?

I choosed java for my restful service back-end for my game, but i'm having such a hard time setting up a simple login system with a mysql database, jwt authentication and spring boot. I followed a great tutorial, but it's only concerning Spring boot, not JWT security.

I would like to move forward and implement the security later if possible.

Right now i just gave up and i'm doing simple apis with just spring boot based on this architecture : https://github.com/djdjalas/SpringBootIn50/tree/master/src/main/java/com/yourname, i replaced the fake data with jdbc calls to the mysql database. Is it ok? Will it be hard to implement autentication later when i will have many services?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security itself is hard to understand and master in the way it should be done as it requires more understanding of the processes behind its configuration. Anyway, if you get familiar with it you won't have serious difficulties here. There will be no major changes to your code. You'll end up generally with one more configuration class/file and this is it.

Can't say anything about JWT but don't think it will be a problem either.

Comment: So you're saying it's not a problem to deal with security later and not immediatly?

Comment: @Benekiki Well, you won't have problems setting login page, authentication and etc it's for sure as it requires configuration class like this one https://github.com/dmitrysenkovich/SpringAdvancedTraining/blob/mine/src/main/java/com/epam/spring/core/web/security/SecurityConfig.java. I'm not sure about JWT but don't thing there will be changes to your operations, just adding logic validating tokens. UPDATE. People add security even after the logic is done because for example if you add login you'll have to login every time you need check something